# Execute Selenium at the startup

Tags: terminal, java, ubuntu-11.10

I'm using Selenium to automate a browser in a Server from a client, but I want that the server execute selenium automatically at the startup.

I have 3 files in /etc/init:

**proxyserver.conf:**

```
respawn 
start on runlevel [23]
script
    exec java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role hub -port 1111
end script
```

**proxyserver2.conf** and **proxyserver3.conf** that are the same thing and change only the content of "script":

```
exec java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=/home/marco/selenium-client/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar -role node -port 2222 -hub http://192.168.1.12:1111 -browserName=chrome,maxInstances=5
```

If I execute this commands at the startup with this method, when I execute Selenium on the Client, it give me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

But if I execute in the terminal the same commands that I use in /etc/init, all works perfectly... why?!

One last thing, if I execute:

```
ps aux | grep selenium
```

when the server the scripts at the startup it gives me:

```
root 746 0.0 12.1 677080 124468 ? Ssl Apr23 8:10 java -Dwebdriver...
root 749 0.0 12.7 685552 130280 ? Ssl Apr23 8.09 java -Dwebdriver...
root 755 0.0 1.9  680168 20240  ? Ssl Apr23 8.08 java -jar selenium...
```

when I execute in the terminal it gives me:

```
1000 9764 6.6  3.0 679236 30992 pts/0 Sl+ 10.33 0:01 java -jar...
1000 9783 14.0 3.0 677112 31752 pts/1 Sl+ 10.33 0:01 java -Dwebdriver...
1000 9792 12.6 3.0 675472 30944 pts/2 Sl+ 10.34 0:01 java -Dwebdriver...
```

Why it can't works?

thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the process created on init is missing some environment variables that you have when run by terminal (`DISPLAY` is one that Selenium will require to know in which display open the browser window).

Try putting this in your init script:

```
env DISPLAY=:0.0
```

More info at [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#environment-variables).